# Django urls Как правильно передать +1 / -1

Tags: django

Не понимаю как передать через `urls.py`, +1 либо же -1.

Пробую так:

```
url(r'^vote/([+/-]/[0-9]+)/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='vote'),
```

но не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если необходимо реализовать возможность голосовать за и против, то лучше так:

```
url(r'^vote/(up|down)/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='vote'),
```

А если возможность голосовать за и против на произвольное количество балов, то:

```
url(r'^vote/([+-]\d+)/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='vote'),
```

**UPDATE:**

Не обратил внимания на то, что у вас [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). Оно ожидает, что в url ему передадут `pk`, а значит url должен быть таким

```
url(r'^vote/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='vote'),
```

, а значение голоса должно передаваться параметром формы, которую этот `UpdateView` обрабатывает.

Если же вам надо в шаблоне генерировать именно ссылку для голосования, то лучше использовать обычное [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#view), в котором определить метод `get(request, vote)` в соответствии с потребностями вашего алгоритма.

Comment: А как я могу принять этот up или down ?
Передавая так в шаблоне, '{% url 'vote' object.id 'up' %}'

во VIew 'self.request.resolver_match'  возвращает:
ResolverMatch(func=myapp.views.VoteView, args=(), kwargs={'object_id': '2'}, url_name=vote, app_names=[], namespaces=[])

Comment: а экранировать не надо  ?